# Specifying JDK 16 in Maven properties

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I think this two lines specify JDK 11.

```
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

I am using Java FX 16 and I compile a code with JDK 16.

When I've tried specify JDK 16:

```
<maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
```

I get this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Unsupported major.minor version 60.0
```

P.S. This is the `pom.xml`: https://pastebin.com/raw/qTe5Vtnq

P.P.S According to logs, I compile and run via `/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk/bin/java`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug.

https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/125

Adding `<executable></executable>` with the absolute path to the JDK 16 should fix it.

Comment: with `<fork>true</fork>`

Answer (score 0):

Put the JDK bin directory of the version you want on your path. That works in most cases, however I'm not certain about the Java Fx bug that is discussed, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -1):

Beyond JDK8, you need to specify the `javac` path of your JDK and you must set `fork` to `true` to get the code executed with mentioned compiler, in `maven-compiler-plugin` `pom.xml` file.

Here is the maven-compiler-plugin configuration,-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>16</source>
        <target>16</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\javac</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Although this would work, a better solution is to put the bin directory on your path.  Then you need not set a executable setting (which may differ by user).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try it once when I do the concerned work regarding this. :)